# How to merge dataframes with multiple conditions/columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have two main frames that I wanted to merge using columns Model, ID, Date&Time.

Here is the first dateframe(df1):

```
ProductName Model       Date&Time
Jugger      2_MXAA_33   2019-08-12 14:37:00
Memz        3_MXA1_44   2019-08-12 14:37:00
```

Second dataframe(df2):

```
Company    ID   Date&Time
A_Company   2   2019-08-12 14:39:00
```

Model and ID should match when the first number of Model is the same as ID. Here is the expected output:

```
ProductName Model       Date&Time            Company    ID
Jugger      2_MXAA_33   2019-08-12 14:37:00  A_Company  2
```

My current solution could only merge using date&time using **`merge_asof`**:

```
tol = pd.Timedelta('2 minute')
merged_df= pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.sort_values('Date&Time'), on='Date&Time', direction="nearest", tolerance=tol)
```

Could you please help on how to also merge using Model and ID columns together with Date&Time? Appreciate the advise on this. Thank you so much.

Comment: create a column in `df1` called `ID`, `merge_asof` has an option called `by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ProductName": ["Jugger", "Memz"],
                    "Model": ["2_MXAA_33", "3_MXA1_44"],
                    "Date&Time": ["2019-08-12 14:37:00", "2019-08-12 14:37:00"]})
df2= pd.DataFrame({"Company": ["A_Company"],
                    "ID": [2],
                    "Date&Time": ["2019-08-12 14:39:00"]})
df1['Date&Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date&Time'])
df2['Date&Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date&Time'])
```

I assume that the `ID` column for `df1` is created by the first number given in `Model`, so create this column:

```
df1["ID"] = df1["Model"].str[0].astype(int)
df1
    ProductName Model       Date&Time               ID
0   Jugger      2_MXAA_33   2019-08-12  14:37:00    2
1   Memz        3_MXA1_44   2019-08-12  14:37:00    3
```

I'm not sure then how you know how to add `Company` to `df1`, but then as @Mark Wang suggests, use `by`:

```
tol = pd.Timedelta('2 minute')
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.sort_values('Date&Time'), on='Date&Time', by="ID", direction="nearest", tolerance=tol)

    ProductName Model       Date&Time           ID  Company
0   Jugger      2_MXAA_33   2019-08-12 14:37:00 2   A_Company
1   Memz        3_MXA1_44   2019-08-12 14:37:00 3   NaN
```

Your final `merge` will look like:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2.sort_values('Date&Time'), on='Date&Time', by=['ID', 'Company'], direction="nearest", tolerance=tol)
```

but again, I'm not sure how to know the `company` for `df1`.

Comment: Thank you! Just want to ask if I could just remove the row which doesn't have a matching ID?

Comment: @LearningNoob Happy to help! Feel free to accept it as an answer if you like. Can you give me an example (maybe by editing your original post) where you have a row that doesn't have a matching ID?